Extending Anchor Chain using Static Rope over Edge
I have a fixed anchor consisting of a ring through a bolt, connected to another bolt with a chain, as show in this image:

Since this anchor point is at the top of a rock, I want to extend it over the edge to toprope on it without my rope rubbing on the edge.
Can I extend this anchor using a static rope? I would tie the rope into the ring using a figure eight and put two locking carabiners into a figure eight at the other end.
I would toprope through the two locking carabiners and use a rope protector on the static rope running over the edge.
Heres a quick sketchup:

Are there any flaws in this approach / easier approaches?
EDIT: updated to clearer image

Is this a sport route? Weird place to put the lower-off.

The biggest issue I see with your proposal is the swing in the static rope. Ideally, you'd want a second anchor point to form a triangle (like if builing a trad anchor/belay).

@Darren It's more of a highball boulder than a sport route really, but someone placed a fixed anchor on top for the more risk-averse crowd.
I hadn't thought about the swinging, I'll think about another anchor point.

Although it should be a minor issue if the climber doesn't deviate to far right or left of the rope, e.g., the direction of pull is mostly downwards on the static rope.

Yes, I suppose you’re right. There’s little difference between this and top-roping directly from the anchor, which people do all the time.

If your "quick sketchup" was posterd as an answer, I'd give it an upvote.

I do not see any issue with this. The anchor is redundant, if you double your static rope, it is redundant as well. Although, with a rope protector, I doubt there will be any issue with rope cutting. Two carabiners opposed are considered safe enough, one of them locking is recommended and two of them locking is as safe as it gets.

The bolts are redundant because of the chain, but the single static rope that might rub against the rock isn't redundant, so I would at least add another length of the rope back up to the chains, or even better, run it to something else so it forms an angle and there's less chance of swinging and rubbing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3PMT6K0_Gg has some examples of what can happen when ropes rub against abrasive rock while swinging. 

Re. Redundancy: people climb on a single top-rope all the time. Agree the rubbing is a concern, but OP has addressed that. And you’d just be rubbing two ropes against the edge anyway.

The bolts are not redundant if the rope/slings/whatnot are tied/looped around the chain. One bolt fails and the anchor fails. No half-twist in the chain (like you can do with webbing) to keep the rope attached to the remaining bolt.

@JonCuster You are not wrong, but the rope is (always) tied into or run through the ring when using such an anchor

If there is a ring - the first graphic (sure, not the real thing) is just a chain between two bolts. A picture of the real setup might help.

@JonCuster The picture shows a ring

No, it has a chain between two bolt hangers. Do not run a rope through those.

@JonCuster the bottom bolt is connected to the chain with a ring. I can see how it looks like just another chain link, I'll update the question with a clearer image.
